# Object (name, surname, index number, table with grades) with a method that calculates the grade average

Tags: javascript, function, methods

So I've been trying to solve this university task. I have an approximate understanding how to solve this, but I only came up with the solutions that either don't work or don't really correspond to the task requirements.

**The task looks like this.**

Create an object using Object initializer, assign properties that describe you (name, surname, index number, table with grades). Assign a method to the object that calculates the grade average

**This is the solution that works but isn't exactly what supposed to be done.**

```
      function Grade (math, science, programming, management){
    this.math = math;
    this.science = science;
    this.programming = programming;
    this.management = management;

    return (math + science + programming + management)/arguments.length;
}

    

const student = {
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Smith', 
        index: 'x4sx4sd',
        grade: Grade(5,4,5,5)
    }

console.log(student);
```

**This is my try that doesn't work but still in my opinion closer to the truth but yet without the average part**

```
const student = {
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Smith', 
        index: 'xxxxx',
        grade: 
        {
            math: 5,
            science: 5,
            language: 5,
            marketing: 5,
            management: 5

        },
        gradeAvg: function(grade){
            grade=this.grade;
            let total = 0;
            for (let value in object){
                total += grade[value]
            }
            return total;  
        }
    
    }

console.log(student);
```

I understand that it's a nooby question, I've tried to google as hard as I could but could find anything, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all you need to convert the grade object from Object to array so you can sum all the elements. [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) does that, so `{a: 1, b: 2}` would become `[1, 2]`. Next you need to get the number of grades so you can then divide the sum to get the average. Last thing you need is a sum of the array we have created previously, [`reduce` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is used to reduce array into one value.

```
        get GradeAvg() {
            const gradesArray = Object.values(this.grade);
            const gradesCount = gradesArray.length;
            const gradesSum = gradesArray.reduce((sum, current) => {
                sum += current;
                return sum;
            })

            return gradesSum / gradesCount;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `gradeAvg` into a `getter` function which will execute when you load in the object. Also, to get the average (whch requires a count) you can access the count using Object.entries (which converts the object into an array) and then get the length

```js
const student = {
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Smith',
  index: 'xxxxx',
  grade: {
    math: 2,
    science: 5,
    language: 5,
    marketing: 1,
    management: 5
  },
  get gradeAvg() {
    let total = 0;
    for (let value in this.grade) {
      total += this.grade[value]
    }
    return total / Object.entries(this.grade).length;
  }
}

console.log(student);
```